# Integration involving product of Bessel K's, polynomial and exponential

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions

This is an integral which I want to solve but could not manage to find any analytical solution in the tables.

$$\int_0^{\infty} x^{\lambda}  e^{-x^2} K_\mu(a x)K_\nu(b x)dx$$

If there is any way to perform the integral, please let me know.

I arrived at the integral while trying to evaluate an apparently more complicated integral involving the Whittaker functions

$$\int_0^{\infty}  x^{\gamma} W_{\mu,\alpha}(x)W_{\mu,\beta}(x) dx $$

and then using the integral representation of Whittaker W. Any known formula to help on this Whittaker integral bypassing the BesselK integral stated above?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The special cases $a=b$ or $\mu=\nu$ are more likely doable.

Comment: As per @Gary's suggestion, the special case of $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\lambda} e^{-x^2} K_{\mu} (a x)^2 \, dx = \frac{2^{\frac{\lambda}{2}-4}}{\pi} G_{4,6}^{6,2}\left(\frac{a^4}{4}\middle|\begin{array}{c}\frac{1-\lambda}{4},\frac{3-\lambda}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\\0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-\mu}{2},-\frac{\mu}{2},\frac{\mu}{2},\frac{\mu+1}{2}\\\end{array}\right)$ where $G$ is the Meijer G function.

Comment: Actually one can do slightly better: $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\lambda} e^{-x^2} K_{\mu} (a x) K_{\nu} (a x) \, dx = \frac{2^{\frac{\lambda}{2}-4}}{\pi} G_{6,8}^{8,2}\left(\frac{a^4}{4}\middle|\begin{array}{c}\frac{1-\lambda}{4},\frac{3-\lambda}{4},0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}\\-\frac{\mu+\nu}{4},-\frac{\mu+\nu-2}{4},\frac{\mu-\nu}{4},\frac{\mu-\nu+2}{4},\frac{\nu-\mu}{4},\frac{-\mu+\nu+2}{4},\frac{\mu+\nu}{4},\frac{\mu+\nu+2}{4}\\\end{array}\right)$

Comment: @KStarGamer Is the other special case $\mu =\nu$ (but $a \neq b$) doable?

Comment: @Gary It doesn't appear so- at least I am not able to obtain it or I would write the answer to OP's question.

Comment: @KStarGamer Pehaps something can be done by using http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E18

Comment: Thanks. A possibly relevant comment: I arrived at the integral while trying to evaluate an apparently more complicated equation involving the Whittaker functions $\int dx x^{\lambda} W_{\mu,\alpha} W_{\mu,\beta}$ and then using the integral representation of Whittaker W.

Comment: @physics_math Ah, a nice example of an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Could you please modify the question and put your original integral in it including the domain of integration?

Comment: Modified the query!

Comment: Gradshteyn and Ryzhik: *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products*, 7th edition, formula 7.611.6.

Comment: @Gary Do you mean [7.611.7](https://i.imgur.com/5xtFsak.jpg)? Note that the formula is not valid for $\lambda - k < \rho$. We have
$$\int_0^\infty x^{\rho - 1} W_{k, \mu}(x) W_{\lambda, \nu}(x) \, dx = \\
\frac 1
 {\Gamma {\left( \frac 1 2 - \lambda - \nu \right)}
  \Gamma {\left( \frac 1 2 - \lambda + \nu \right)}}
G_{3, 3}^{2, 3} {\left( 1 \middle|
 {\frac 1 2 - \rho - \mu, \frac 1 2 - \rho + \mu, \lambda + 1 \atop
  \frac 1 2 - \nu, \frac 1 2 + \nu, k - \rho} \right)},$$
Slater's theorem is not applicable if $\lambda - k < \rho$.

Comment: @Maxim Yes, that is what I meant. I tried to copy the number carefully yet failed. I did not check the conditions and the OP did not give any either. By Slater's theorem, do you mean [this](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.17.E2)?